# How to redirect non www to www in aws s3 bucket and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I know how to redirect/rewrite non-www to www using .htaccess in apache server. But I have no clue, about s3 bucket, and CloudFront. I have hosted the website on an s3 bucket using CloudFront.

How do I redirect all http://example.com/ requests to http://www.example.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more information so that we can better assist you. For example: Is example.com currently being served out of an Amazon S3 bucket? How are you using CloudFront? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a feature in S3 where you can to this. Select a bucket, in **Properties** under **Static Web Hosting** select **Redirect all requests to another host name**.

Read more here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/

Update from comment:
Add a cname in your domain setup for example.com to point to your bucket endpoint and a cname for your www.example.com to point to the cloudfront endpoint.

Comment: This is not useful. i tried this. redirect all request to it just point to another bucket.

Comment: It work only in case of s3 bucket and route 53 configuration. but if we are using cloudfront with this. then its now working.

Comment: Then I am not sure if I understand your question. Add a cname in your domain setup for example.com to point to your bucket endpoint and a cname for your www.example.com to point to the cloudfront endpoint.

Comment: The question clearly states Cloudfront. I cannot see how this is the answer.

Did you add a second CloudFront Distribution for the base domain, it would be great if this answers this question because this question is not answered.anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

1. Create a `www.example.com` S3 bucket and place all the code in this bucket
2. Create a `example.com` S3 bucket and set redirect to `www.example.com` as mentioned in  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/
3. Create CloudFront and configure with S3 bucket link of `www.example.com` and add `cname` entry only for `www.example.com`.
4. In Route 53 for `www.example.com` point alias as CloudFront link related to S3 bucket
5. In Route 53 for `example.com` point alias S3 bucket of `example.com`

Comment: Does this only work with CloudFront?

Comment: Yes. this routing configuration for CloduFront. But similar can you do for only S3 bucket hosting too.

Comment: Here is what I used and it was extremely simple after hours of searching: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to allow redirecting from non-www to www, the easiest way is

1. Create two S3 buckets with name exact domain name (example.com and
   [www.example.com](http://www.example.com))
2. Enable bucket policy for public access
3. Enable a static website for both domains, however, we will config
   redirect for example.com.
4. Create two CloudFront for the two S3 buckets Create two alias A
   records for example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and route them to the
   two CloudFront respectively.

Link reference: https://www.galireview.com/blog/static-website-on-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/