# Redirect to WWW not working in chrome with S3 static website hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I have hosted a static website on AWS S3 with a custom domain (purchased from crazy domain). I have obtained SSL certificate from AWS ACM.

I need to redirect bare domain **"example.com"** to "https://www.example.com".
Following are the steps I have followed so far -

1. Created 2 buckets on S3 - **example.com** (Used for redirection) and **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** (Used for website hosting)
2. Created 2 cloudfront distribution -
   One with **"Origin Domain Name"** as **"example.com.s3.amazonaws.com"** and another with another with **"Origin Domain Name"** as **"www.example.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.c
   om"**
3. Created **CNAME** record set on crazy domain with **WWW** pointing to cloudfront distribution as

[image]

4. Added **"A"** record set in **Route53** for both cloudfront distributions.

When I enter example.com in Firefox and Safari, it is redirecting to https://www.example.com but in Chrome it is showing `This site can’t be reached`

Can anyone please let me know if there is anything specific I need to do for Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried in incognito window of chrome ? if its working other browser and not in chrome might be cache issue. You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000416/how-to-redirect-non-www-to-www-in-aws-s3-bucket-and-cloudfront

Comment: @aviboy2006 - Yes I have tried it in Incognito mode as well as in different computers but having same issue with all. You can check it at your end if you want tripsafe.co

Comment: CloudFront url is working in chrome ?

Comment: Yes CloudFront URL is working properly and redirecting to www with HTTPS protocol

Comment: Another thing can do open debugger and hit request and see how redirecting happening.

Comment: If possible to give link ?

Comment: Please check tripsafe.co

Comment: See this setting once explain here https://www.internetkatta.com/rewrite-non-www-to-www-in-aws-s3-bucket-and-cloudfront

Comment: https://www.internetkatta.com/rewrite-non-www-to-www-in-aws-s3-bucket-and-cloudfront it working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223105/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-sachin-vairagi).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figure it out as -

1. Added **NS** record set from **Route53** to Crazy domain
2. Removed **CNAME** record set with **www**
3. Added **Web Forward** record set in crazy domain

[image]