# What am I missing in my AWS Route 53 S3 simple hosting setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I've got 5 records in my AWS Route 53 hosted zone:
First is an NS for my domain name.
Second  is SOA for that domain.
Third is a validated CNAME for it.
Fourth is cloudfront distribution A alias for it with the www prefix.
Fifth is validated CNAME for the www version.

I don't yet have an SSL attached to it.

It works - well partially.

Trying to reach the unprefixed version of the domain from Chrome doesn't work, but if I type the domain with the www prefix it works.

Firefox automatically redirects the unprefixed domain to the www variant. I type the unprefixed name making sure it's not redirecting because the prefixed name is in the search history. When I hit enter, Firefox automatically redirects to the www.

I'd like the main name to be accessible, not just the www one. It's OK if someone types the www. They should get to the site, but the actual name has no www.

I'm inexperienced enough not to be certain about that www prefix or why it is necessary. This was the result of a long course on AWS services.

Can anyone tell me if I'm missing a needed record, or if I'm improperly using the Alias A record?

Edited to add this below after reading first three answers. Thank all of you who answered for your responses. I do appreciate them. Please see my comments on those answers. --

I'm attaching a screenshot of my Route 53 hosted zone settings to maybe help you get a clearer picture of where I am.

Please remember. I'm not starting with a domain with a site that I wanted to host on S3 and then redirect www.mydomain traffic to mydomain.

I began coding an app with no domain. Then I uploaded it to an S3 bucket. I then was able to access it's simple S3 hosting with the ugly url. Then I used CloudFront for a world-wide distribution, again with an ugly url. Only then did I try taking one of my owned subdomains and redirecting it to Route 53. It wasn't as clean and simple as buying a domain from Amazon. I had no SSL and had to make a request for the AWS Certificate Manager to process validation of my domain. I got all that.

My problem is as I tried to explain - Chrome won't recognize or redirect my main domain name without the www. It only recognizes if one types the www. in front of the domain name. On the other hand, Firefox automatically redirects no matter what you type (the www version or the one without the www). That redirection is to the www version (that is what shows in the url bar in the end - http://www.mydomain).

[image: R-53 hosted zone]

Comment: What domains is your ssl cert registered to ? Only www version?

Comment: [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000416/how-to-redirect-non-www-to-www-in-aws-s3-bucket-and-cloudfront see answer.

Comment: to Marcin: I have no ssl certificate yet, so neither version.

Comment: to John Rotenstein: Those generic instructions dont' work for me very well. I had already created my S3 bucket without the domain name. Everything worked fine. I then also created a CloudFront distribution. It also worked fine. I created the domain name record set in a hosting zone in Route 53. First I had to apply for AWS Certificates, which I got. My question is really at the stage of the Route 53 record set creation. Those instructions take me to a completely new path I had never started in the first place. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think you need two buckets. Course used only one.

Comment: to aviboy2006: I read Jeff Barr's article. That's also not helpful. It assumes you're starting from scratch to redirect your S3 bucket deployed static web hosting site. While he uses the Route 53 hosted zone, he only mentions creating two Alias A records there and adding them to your domain's DNS zone (no mention of how they're set (the name servers NS, or the SOA and the CNAMES. He just says add two Aliases (one for the main domain name and another for the www version). Nice pictures, but no details explained.

Comment: I got SSL certificates approved & validated by AWS on both the main domain and the www version. Typing https:// now recognized by browsers, I noticed that I did not have an Alias CNAME created for the main domain above in my R 53 hosted zone for my CloudFront Distribution, so I also fixed that. Dunno if I really had to black out the DNS & SOA sections, but the ones on the validation codes for the SSLs seemed appropriate. I don't know enough about security, so maybe overly cautious.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured out most of this. As I mentioned in my comment above, I noticed I didn't have an Alias record for my main domain. I also read in AWS documentation that my S3 hosting bucket should have the same name as the domain, so I did that.

After creating the new original S3 hosting bucket I had made another to keep the log files. I set up a CloudFront Distribution. Then I requested and got SSL certificates for my owned domain name and added another for the www version. With those successfully enabled, I transferred my registered DNS servers to AWS. That created the NS and SOA records when I created my R-53 hosted zone. I then created Alias records for both the man and www version and added the validated SSL certificates for both the main domain and the www version. So, a total of six records in the zone.

I created my new S3 bucket, naming it the same as my domain; copied the settings from the old one, set it up to host static single page site and generate logs. I had already created a bucket for the logs, so I just pointed the logs location for the new domain named bucket. I gave the regular logs a log prefix (folder) and the CloudFront logs a cdn one.

Everything works great except I discovered a new problem. I'll post a new question regarding that, something like XML error on browser refresh in child pages.

Thanks ALL!