# To consolidate www and non-www, should I use an A record in Route 53 or two CloudFront distributions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

## Issue

I have a static website hosted on AWS S3. There are two buckets: mywebsite.com hosts the actual files, and [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) redirects to the former. The domain is registered in Route 53, and I have a CloudFront distribution to speed things up and ensure https is used. I also [add security headers using Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/).

My website connects to an API Gateway and, since CORS does not allow multiple domains (i.e. mywebsite.com and [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)), I need to ensure all requests to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) are redirected to mywebsite.com (in addition to http redirecting to https). This domain redirect happened when I only had S3 but, after [following AWS documentation to add CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html#update-record-sets), this is no longer the case:

> If the browser no longer redirects you to the root domain (for example, http://example.com), the new A records are in place.

So the question is: **How do I retain the benefits of CloudFront, while reinstating the domain redirect?**

## Research

I found two relevant SO questions, both about 5 years old:

1. [How to redirect non www to www in aws s3 bucket and cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000416/how-to-redirect-non-www-to-www-in-aws-s3-bucket-and-cloudfront)
2. [Supporting HTTPS URL redirection with a single CloudFront distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614734/supporting-https-url-redirection-with-a-single-cloudfront-distribution)

However, **their solutions are different, and I am trying to understand the tradeoffs.**

The former suggests that I:

- Edit my Route 53 A record for [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) to point to the S3 bucket for [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) (instead of CloudFront distribution), and
- Modify the CloudFront distribution to remove [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) from its CNAMEs.

Note that I am referring to the solution by the question asker (not the accepted answer), and this question's domain remapping is the reverse of mine.

The latter suggests that I:

- Create a second CloudFront distribution that maps [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) to the corresponding S3 bucket (editing my Route 53 A record for [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) to point to this new distribution), and
- Modify the existing CloudFront distribution to only process mywebsite.com.

So the second step of both solutions is identical, but the first part differs, and I am trying to understand what impact this would have.

**Basically the difference seems to boil down to whether the second step in this sequence exists:**

1. www.mywebsite.com's Route 53 A record -->
2. 2nd CloudFront distribution -->
3. empty S3 bucket with redirect -->
4. mywebsite.com's Route 53 A record -->
5. original CloudFront distribution (which triggers Lambda@Edge) -->
6. S3 bucket with actual website files

If the user enters mywebsite.com, either with http or https, we start at stage 4 and there's no difference as far as I can tell. But I'm unclear on what difference this CloudFront distribution makes if the user enters http://www.mywebsite.com or https://www.mywebsite.com:

- Will http://www.mywebsite.com work equivalently in both cases?
- Will https://www.mywebsite.com be broken without a second CloudFront distribution, because S3 bucket only supports http?
- Since all requests ultimately go through CloudFront in step 5, I assume Lambda@Edge only needs to be triggered there?

Lastly, **am I correct that it does not matter whether I redirect [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) to mywebsite.com or vice-versa?** I am choosing the former because that is how the AWS documentation guided me when setting up the S3 buckets, but their CloudFront instructions also ensured API Gateway + CORS would fail by not consolidating both domains, so I want to make sure I'm not painting myself into another future corner.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently following the steps mentioned in the document: [Static website on amazon s3 and CloudFront](https://www.galireview.com/blog/static-website-on-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/)

In general, using two s3 buckets and configuring bucket policies and two CloudFront can solve my issue. Hope the link can help you solve the issue!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34674794)